# How to manipulate json data with AND, OR and NOT operators to get possible conditions

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, json

I have a JSON Object, which have pre and post filters for different payment types. I have to compute the possible combinations of inputs which can be passed for another API.

JSON Example:

```
{
 "refund": {
   "preFilters": {
     "type": [ "1" ]
   },
   "postFilters": {
     "flag2": [ "123", "678" ],
     "flag5": [ "907", "8752" ]
   }
}
```

Here, I need to get possible conditions that can be computed through AND, OR and NOT operators. Example, in this json I have to get the below 16 combinations:

```
 1= type & (flag2 & flag5),
 2= type & (flag2 | flag5),
 3= type & (!flag2 & !flag5),
 4= type & (!flag2 & flag5),
 5= type & (flag2 | !flag5),
 6= type & (!flag2 | !flag5),
 7= type & (!flag2 | flag5),
 8= type & (flag2 | !flag5),
 9= type | (flag2 & flag5),
 10=type | (flag2 | flag5),
 11=type | (!flag2 & !flag5),
 12=type | (!flag2 & flag5),
 13=type | (flag2 & !flag5),
 14=type | (!flag2 | !flag5),
 15=type | (!flag2 | flag5),
 16=type | (flag2 | !flag5)
```

And, also the type in preFilters and flag values in postFilters can have multiple values.I need to derive these set of possible conditions using And, Or and Not operators with values from pre and post filters.

Any advice or solution will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why is this tagged with both JS and Java?

Comment: Can't you just use `if condition1 else if condition2 else if ...` statements?

Comment: Are you looking for logical or bitwise operations?  For example, what is the expected output of operation 1 on your sample data?

Answer (score 0):

Make an array of functions matching the structure of your list of algorithms, then you can iterate the arrays in your data and apply those functions

```js
const algos = [
  (type, flag2, flag5) => type & (flag2 & flag5),
  (type, flag2, flag5) => type & (flag2 | flag5),
  (type, flag2, flag5) => type & (~flag2 & ~flag5)
  // etc
];

const data = {
 "refund": {
   "preFilters": {
     "type": [ "1" ]
   },
   "postFilters": {
     "flag2": [ "123", "678" ],
     "flag5": [ "907", "8752" ]
   }
 }
};

let output = [];
data.refund.preFilters.type.forEach(t => {
  data.refund.postFilters.flag2.forEach(f2 => {
    data.refund.postFilters.flag5.forEach(f5 => {
      output.push({
        type: t, 
        flag2: f2, 
        flag5: f5, 
        results: algos.map(algo => algo(t, f2, f5))
      });
    });
  });
});
console.log(output);
```